# Sqlite python INSERT query dont work for me

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to add data to a simple SQLite database. I'm using python 2.7 and newest SQLite. The code below executes without any errors but nothing is added into table. Its is piece of code which should be writing voltage values from arduino into sqlite table on a Raspberry Pi (right now for simplifying the problem I'm using some random values, no variables). I'm able to put anything in the table using "INSERT" command within sqlite command line itself, but from python no luck. Is it incompatible with earlier versions of python than 3 or something like that?

```
import serial
import sys
import sqlite3
import time
from datetime import datetime
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
# sys.stdout = open('test22output.txt','wt')

conn=sqlite3.connect('test1.db')
curs=conn.cursor()
def data_entry():
  curs.execute("""INSERT INTO temps values(date('now'),
    time('now'), Ano, 27)""")
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no, but i solved it, i deleted    def data_entry():    and now it works but iam getting    sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column:    Ano

Answer (score 0):

You never call the `data_entry()` function.

I'm not sure why you've put that line into a function at all; this is a simple script, you could just have that code inline with the rest.

Comment: allright, so i deleted it and its working it has some sort of connection with .db file now because its telling me sqlite3. $ OperationalError: no such column: Ano $ but i dont want to add anything into column Ano, i want word Ano to be written in 3rd column why it doesnt work like that?  BUT many thanks it work lets say...better right now. DO you know how to fix that "no such column" error?

Comment: You need to put it in quotes: `'Ano'`.

Comment: YES! that works, sorry for my lack of knowledge, iam going to buy a book or something.... THANKS :)